# Untar a file in an OS X directory with QProcess

Tags: qt, tar, qprocess, qt5.1

I'm trying to `untar` a file with `QProcess` that's in a directory returned by `QDir::tempPath()`, as follows:

```
extract.start("tar", QStringList() << "-xvzf" + QDir::tempPath() + "/thefile.tar.gz");
```

I get the correct output for an extraction by looking at the `standardOuput` for the `QProcess` but there's no file extracted at the end. Manually running `tar` from a shell works fine on the file so I know it's not corrupt, I'd have assumed a permissions issue but I'm actually downloading the file with the application to the temporary directory so the application should have write access.

Edit: I've also now tried it with the file in the home directory, it's definitely there but I get the same results as it being in the temp directory, verbose output indicating success but no resulting file.

Comment: Does the path returned by tempPath contain any spaces? If so, you'll probably need to surround that in quotes.

Comment: No spaces, I'd initially made a mistake and left a space after the `-xvzf` and `tar` wouldn't work at all. I do get some output from the standard read channels but no output file.

Comment: Where are you looking for the file? I expect it will generate it in the current working directory, whatever that is when your program runs.

Comment: Looking in the temporary directory retrieved by `QDir::tempPath()`, I've also just tried it with the file in the home dir and it failed as well.

Comment: Have you set the tempPath to be the current working directory? QProcess::setWorkingDirectory

Comment: No, I've also dumped the the temp path (/var/folders/1t/somelongstring/T) to make sure it's there, and verified the file to be there.

Comment: Weird, you were right, it's not actually extracting it into the temp dir, it's extracting it into the `.app` bundle `Contents` instead. If you pop that as an answer I'll accept it. Not sure *why* it's defaulting there but I'll just force it to extract in temp instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the working directory, which by default, is likely to be the folder of the executable's binary.

You can set the working directory with **QProcess::setWorkingDirectory**